# AWS access keys and IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

In AWS, why is access key created in the context of a user even though when you configure CLI / SDK, you never provide the user associated with the access key and instead it is only the access key (access key id and secret access key)  that is specified?

1. What is the real benefit of having access key tied to a user?
2. Isn't it an overhead to also have a user if someone only wants programmatic access - Or is it so that API calls become more readable with a user than having to list a lengthy access key id when looking in CloudTrail?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using both AWS and GCP, and GCP has users IAM and 'service account' which is needed for each service call

As you know GCP comes later than AWS and your concern could be valid. The latter GCP has some advantage :P

In the meantime, AWS IAM was there since they launched the service, and it works so many years.

It just needs your system admin to standardize the user management, e.g. programmatic account starts the name with cli_, and ensure programmatic access only for this kind of accounts